# How do I remove the space between div and top of page?

Tags: css, html, margin

This has probably been asked a million and one times, but I would appreciate it if someone could explain the behavior of the divs to me..

I have a container div which I am aligning in the center of the page, which has a gap between the top and the top of the page. I want it to be flush against the top of the page. I am assuming that there is some sort of margin or padding that I need to remove but I can't think what it could be. Even with nothing in the div there is still a gap.

```
    <body>
    <div id='mainContent'>

    </div>
</body>


body
{
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url("img/background.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

#mainContent
{
    width:1200px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H76bq/) to give you an idea of what I mean.

Can someone please explain why the div is pushed down as it is? Is there a robust solution that doesn't affect any content that is put in the div??

NOTE: If the screen width is smaller than the div width, there will be a gap on the left hand side aswell.

Answer (score 20):

You need to reset the default margin of the `body` that is 8px aprox.

```
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

The Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/H76bq/3/**

For default all elements has some properties:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

You can reset this in your own css.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a star selector and reset everything so that you can set everything yourself:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }
```

Or if you wanted to use a master reset stylesheet you could use Jonathan Neal's [**Normalize CSS**](http://normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css) via Google CDN.

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all
>   elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We researched
>   the differences between default browser styles in order to precisely target
>   only the styles that need normalizing.

Just put this in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also been caused by `line-height` property.
So set the `line-height` to as you wish!

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0px;` to `body` like below. The reason is because `body` by default introduces a margin.

```
body{
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url("img/background.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H76bq/6/)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem and I solved it by setting negative margin. You could test the below setting.

```
 #mainContent {... margin-top:-25px;}
```